# Sync data and conflict resolve module testing

Tags: test-design

We have an application which track the animal data in various locations called stations. Even without internet they user can save the data to local machine. Once those data save in the local pc they need to transfer (sync) these data to main office (local PC connect to local offices and get the data) database and save there. When local office user again want to get save the data of local office he or she need to sync down data from main office. In this sync up and down conflicts can happen. We have tool developed to handle the sync and sync down , also the  conflict resolution

We need to test this scenarios for various combinations. What are the possible test combinations ?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Start by breaking that scenario into discrete steps.  Then think about what can go wrong in each step.  For example, one step is "sync data from local PC to main office".  What happens if the communication link fails in the middle of a sync?  Does the sync pick up where it left off, or does it restart from beginning, or does it resume somewhere in the middle?

Comment: What are the functional and non-functional requirements for the application?

Comment: We have not discuss the non functional for this yet but when sync data from local users PC to head office performance need to consider

Comment: Requirement : We have an application which track the animal data in various locations called stations. Even without internet they user can save the data to local machine. Once those data save in the local pc they need to transfer (sync) these data to main office (local PC connect to local offices and get the data) database and save there. When local office user again want to get save the data of local office he or she need to sync down data from main office. In this sync up and down conflicts can happen. We have tool developed to handle the sync and sync down , also the conflict resolution